# How to convert Images from database(cloud) to timelapse video via raspberry pi?

Tags: pi-2

hye, my project is about timelapse but we are not using the rpi camera to capture the images instead we are using DSLR camera for some reasons. once it captures, the images would be saved into the database. How could we actually use the images from the database to convert into a video by giving the command to raspberry Pi? Most of the solutions I've searched regarding the rpi camera module which the rpi camera captures and it converts to video.Can you help me how to actually to call the database into rpi? thank you Hope u understand my problem.

Comment: You would have to give much more information about the database. Converting images to a movie is easy, you need to figure out how to get the images from the database, do some research on that, not on video creation.

Comment: I fear you've come to the wrong place for help with that. The good news is that there are several tools available that will convert your still images into a timelapse.

Comment: Thanks for the responds, @ChadG. Appreciate for the responds during this tough  moment, the sense of hopes to finish this project on time.

Comment: Thanks for the responds, @Seamus. Appreciate for the responds during this tough moment, the sense of hopes to finish this project on time.

Comment: You're welcome, and I hope you are successful with your timelapse. As you've seen, there are many choices for software to convert a sequence of stills into a timelapse. Some are free, and some you'll need to pay for. If you were using the Raspberry Pi camera, it would be easy for us to help you, but you probably need better image quality that you'd get from the Pi Camera. Best of luck!